# Thinking about a way to organize database

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays

I am making a function that will show what are the articles of the site that are currently being visited, ordered by the number of current visitors. Everytime someone visits an article, it adds his informations to the DB. This is how my BD is made:

First col is IP_Adress, second col is Article_ID, last col is Timestamp.

I need to order my data with which articles currently have the most visitors on it, but my entries are dependent of the IP Adress (because the Ip Adress are unique in the DB, since when a visitor changes page, it only modifies the Article ID & timestamp, it does not create another entry), not of the Article ID.

I am stuck there, hopefuly someone will have an answer for me :).

Thank you!

Comment: By current visitors do you mean those still on the site or all visitors so far, the second is much easier.

Comment: And of course the obligatory "what have you tried"

Comment: I mean all those that are in the DB (they get deleted after 10minutes, this is why I have a timestamp)

Comment: I have not tried anything, because I have no idea what to do. There is nothing I can do with ORDER BY, because that will not let me say this post has 5 visitors, this one has 4, this one has 3, so there order is: post that have 5 visitors, post that has 4 visitors, post that has 3 visitors, etc.

Comment: Then you need to use GROUP BY Article_ID

Comment: Both answers are equivalent, @sgeddes just sorts them for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Select Article_ID, count(Article_ID) 
    from yourtable 
    group by Article_ID
```

Comment: This query returns me int 1

Comment: Which query function are you using, which language? Was an error logged in last_error or whatever your system uses?

Comment: There should be a Record set that you need to read after you execute the query.

Comment: Is it suppose to return int 1 ?

Comment: What function did you use to execute the query is this PHP?

Comment: $idbd = $wpdb->query("SELECT count(*), Post_ID FROM wp_pagesvisites GROUP BY Post_ID");       This is the wordpress db handler

Comment: $wpdb->query() should only be used for executable queries, as it only returns the number of rows or false if no rows

Comment: You got it! I needed to use get_results instead of query. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome and good luck with the project.

Comment: +1 for typing faster than me on the response (even with an iPad) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Count(*), Article_id
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Article_id
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC
```

This will give you which article has the most current visitors.

Good luck and let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: What are the Count(*) for?

Comment: It returns the number of rows in the group. I use count((Article_ID) they return the same thing.

Comment: You asked to know which articles had the most users -- showing that count and ordering by allow you to know this.  Technically you can remove the Count(*) from your select and just keep in your ORDER BY to get the same results.  But I assumed you wanted to know how many visitors were accessing each article (some might have the same number).  Good luck.

Comment: Take a look at the SQL Fiddle -- perhaps it will help explain it to you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/470178/2  -- Hope that helps.

Comment: wow this is great!! But this query returns only int 1 for me...It should return an array at least? Thank you for this great help though.

Comment: I haven't used WordPress much before, but I think you need to use $wpdb->get_results().

Comment: $wpdb->query() should only be used for executable queries, as it only returns the number of rows or false if no rows

Comment: peter was the first to answer, but you both helped me as much, thanks again.

Comment: +1 for the sorting and assistance while I fought with trying to type code on an iPad.